# Rendering Swing Components to an Offscreen buffer

Tags: java, swing

I have a Java (Swing) application, running on a 32-bit Windows 2008 Server, which needs to render it's output to an off-screen image (which is then picked up by another C++ application for rendering elsewhere). Most of the components render correctly, except in the odd case where a component which has just lost focus is occluded by another component, for example where there are two JComboBoxes close to each other, if the user interacts with the lower one, then clicks on the upper one so it's pull-down overlaps the other box.

In this situation, the component which has lost focus is rendered after the one occluding it, and so appears on top in the output. It renders correctly in the normal Java display (running full-screen on the primary display), and attempting to change the layers of the components in question does not help.

I am using a custom RepaintManager to paint the components to the offscreen image, and I assume the problem lies with the order in which addDirtyRegion() is called for each of the components in question, but I can't think of a good way of identifying when this particular state occurs in order to prevent it. Hacking it so that the object which has just lost focus is not repainted stops the problem, but obviously causes the bigger problem that it is not repainted in all other, normal, circumstances.

Is there any way of programmatically identifying this state, or of reordering things so that it does not occur?

Many thanks,

Nick

[edit]
Added some code as an example:

Repaint manager and associated classes:

```
class NativeObject {
    private long nativeAddress = -1;

    protected void setNativeAddress(long address) {
        if ( nativeAddress != -1 ) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("native address already set for " + this);
        }
        this.nativeAddress = address;
        NativeObjectManager.getInstance().registerNativeObject(this, nativeAddress);
    }   
}

public class MemoryMappedFile extends NativeObject {
    private ByteBuffer buffer;

    public MemoryMappedFile(String name, int size)
    {
        setNativeAddress(create(name, size));
        buffer = getNativeBuffer();
    }

    private native long create(String name, int size);

    private native ByteBuffer getNativeBuffer();

    public native void lock();

    public native void unlock();

    public ByteBuffer getBuffer() {
        return buffer;
    }
}

private static class CustomRepaintManager extends RepaintManager{       
    class PaintLog {
        Rectangle bounds;
        Component component;
        Window window;

        PaintLog(int x, int y, int w, int h, Component c) {
            bounds = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
            this.component = c;
        }

        PaintLog(int x, int y, int w, int h, Window win) {
            bounds = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
            this.window= win;
        }
    }

    private MemoryMappedFile memoryMappedFile;
    private BufferedImage offscreenImage;
    private List<PaintLog> regions = new LinkedList<PaintLog>();
    private final Component contentPane;
    private Component lastFocusOwner;
    private Runnable sharedMemoryUpdater;
    private final IMetadataSource metadataSource;
    private Graphics2D offscreenGraphics;
    private Rectangle offscreenBounds = new Rectangle();
    private Rectangle repaintBounds = new Rectangle();

    public CustomRepaintManager(Component contentPane, IMetadataSource metadataSource) {
        this.contentPane = contentPane;
        this.metadataSource = metadataSource;
        offscreenBounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1920, 1080);  
        memoryMappedFile = new MemoryMappedFile("SystemConfigImage", offscreenBounds.width * offscreenBounds.height * 3 + 1024);
        offscreenImage = new BufferedImage(offscreenBounds.width, offscreenBounds.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        offscreenGraphics = offscreenImage.createGraphics();

        sharedMemoryUpdater = new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                updateSharedMemory();
            }
        };
    }

    private boolean getLocationRelativeToContentPane(Component c, Point screen) {
        if(!c.isVisible()) {
            return false;
        }

        if(c == contentPane) {
            return true;
        }

        Container parent = c.getParent();
        if(parent == null) {
            System.out.println("can't get parent!");
            return true;
        }

        if(!parent.isVisible()) {
            return false;
        }

        while ( !parent.equals(contentPane)) {
            screen.x += parent.getX();
            screen.y += parent.getY();
            parent = parent.getParent();

            if(parent == null) {
                System.out.println("can't get parent!");
                return true;
            }
            if(!parent.isVisible()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected void updateSharedMemory() {
        if ( regions.isEmpty() ) return;

        List<PaintLog> regionsCopy = new LinkedList<PaintLog>();

        synchronized ( regions ) {
            regionsCopy.addAll(regions);
            regions.clear();
        }

        memoryMappedFile.lock();
        ByteBuffer mappedBuffer = memoryMappedFile.getBuffer();
        int imageDataSize = offscreenImage.getWidth() * offscreenImage.getHeight() * 3;
        mappedBuffer.position(imageDataSize);

        if ( mappedBuffer.getInt() == 0 ) {
            repaintBounds.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
        } else {
            repaintBounds.x = mappedBuffer.getInt();
            repaintBounds.y = mappedBuffer.getInt();
            repaintBounds.width = mappedBuffer.getInt();
            repaintBounds.height = mappedBuffer.getInt();
        }

        for ( PaintLog region : regionsCopy ) {
            if ( region.component != null  && region.bounds.width > 0 && region.bounds.height > 0) {
                Point regionLocation = new Point(region.bounds.x, region.bounds.y);
                Point screenLocation = region.component.getLocation();
                boolean isVisible = getLocationRelativeToContentPane(region.component, screenLocation);

                if(!isVisible) {
                    continue;
                }

                if(region.bounds.x != 0 && screenLocation.x == 0 || region.bounds.y != 0 && screenLocation.y == 0){
                    region.bounds.width += region.bounds.x;
                    region.bounds.height += region.bounds.y;
                }

                Rectangle2D.intersect(region.bounds, offscreenBounds, region.bounds);

                if ( repaintBounds.isEmpty() ){
                    repaintBounds.setBounds( screenLocation.x, screenLocation.y, region.bounds.width, region.bounds.height);
                } else {
                    Rectangle2D.union(repaintBounds, new Rectangle(screenLocation.x, screenLocation.y, region.bounds.width, region.bounds.height), repaintBounds);
                }

                offscreenGraphics.translate(screenLocation.x, screenLocation.y);

                region.component.paint(offscreenGraphics);

                DataBufferByte byteBuffer = (DataBufferByte) offscreenImage.getData().getDataBuffer();
                int srcIndex = (screenLocation.x + screenLocation.y * offscreenImage.getWidth()) * 3;
                byte[] srcData = byteBuffer.getData();

                int maxY = Math.min(screenLocation.y + region.bounds.height, offscreenImage.getHeight());
                int regionLineSize = region.bounds.width * 3;

                for (int y = screenLocation.y; y < maxY; ++y){
                    mappedBuffer.position(srcIndex);

                    if ( srcIndex + regionLineSize > srcData.length ) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if ( srcIndex + regionLineSize > mappedBuffer.capacity() ) {
                        break;
                    }
                    try {
                        mappedBuffer.put( srcData, srcIndex, regionLineSize);
                    }
                    catch ( IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                        break;
                    }
                    srcIndex += 3 * offscreenImage.getWidth();
                }

                offscreenGraphics.translate(-screenLocation.x, -screenLocation.y);
                offscreenGraphics.setClip(null);

            } else if ( region.window != null ){    
                repaintBounds.setBounds(0, 0, offscreenImage.getWidth(), offscreenImage.getHeight() );

                offscreenGraphics.setClip(repaintBounds);

                contentPane.paint(offscreenGraphics);

                DataBufferByte byteBuffer = (DataBufferByte) offscreenImage.getData().getDataBuffer();
                mappedBuffer.position(0);
                mappedBuffer.put(byteBuffer.getData());
            }
        }

        mappedBuffer.position(imageDataSize);
        mappedBuffer.putInt(repaintBounds.isEmpty() ? 0 : 1);
        mappedBuffer.putInt(repaintBounds.x);
        mappedBuffer.putInt(repaintBounds.y);
        mappedBuffer.putInt(repaintBounds.width);
        mappedBuffer.putInt(repaintBounds.height);
        metadataSource.writeMetadata(mappedBuffer);

        memoryMappedFile.unlock();
    }

    @Override
    public void addDirtyRegion(JComponent c, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        super.addDirtyRegion(c, x, y, w, h);
        synchronized ( regions ) {
            regions.add(new PaintLog(x, y, w, h, c));
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(sharedMemoryUpdater);
    }

    @Override
    public void addDirtyRegion(Window window, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        super.addDirtyRegion(window, x, y, w, h);
        synchronized (regions) {    
            regions.add(new PaintLog(x, y, w, h, window));
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(sharedMemoryUpdater);
    }
}
```

The Panel that is having the problems:

```
private static class EncodingParametersPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
    private JComboBox comboBox1 = new JComboBox();

    private JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
    private JComboBox comboBox2 = new JComboBox();

    private JLabel label3 = new JLabel();
    private JComboBox comboBox3 = new JComboBox();

    private JButton setButton = new JButton();

    public EncodingParametersPanel()
    {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel(new VerticalFlowLayout());
        JPanel formatPanel = new JPanel(new VerticalFlowLayout());

        sdiFormatPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder(), "Format"));

        label1.setText("First Option:");
        label2.setText("Second Option:");
        label3.setText("Third OPtion:");

        setButton.addActionListener(this);

        formatPanel.add(label1);
        formatPanel.add(comboBox1);
        formatPanel.add(label2);
        formatPanel.add(comboBox2);
        formatPanel.add(label3);
        formatPanel.add(comboBox3);

        contentPanel.add(formatPanel);

        contentPanel.add(setButton);

        add(contentPanel);
    }
}
```

Using this example, if the user interacts with comboBox2, then with comboBox1, the pull-down from comboBox1 overlaps comboBox2, but comboBox2 is redrawn on top of it.

Comment: What happens when you use the default RepaintManager? Also, I don't understand how you initiate the rendering of the components. For example if I have an open combo box and click on a button to initiate some action, the combo box closes, so I don't know how to reproduce the situation you describe. I suggest help post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use the default repaint manager as it has to also write some metadata for the C++ application to use, e.g. identifying dirty regions in the offscreen image for the C++ app to redraw.

Rendering is initiated by the standard means, all I have replaced in the main JFrame is the RepaintManager, so as far as I understand it, each component should cause a repaint when it becomes invalid?

I'm not sure I can post a full example due to the nature of the native code involved, but I'll put up the java side of it.

Comment: In the for loop in updateSharedMemory, the big if-else chain has no final else. Try adding that and seeing if there are regions you're not handling.

Comment: Well spotted, thanks! There are a few regions with both width and height == 0, but no other nonzero ones that aren't already caught by the two main blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a couple of things that could contribute to what you are seeing.

In the `updateSharedMemory` code for handling a repaint of a Window, the code calls `contentPane.paint`. This is the most likely culprit as the Window might not be your contentPane. The code for JPopupMenu (which is used by JComboBox) may choose to present the popup as a heavyweight component. So, the Window could be the popup of one of the JComboBoxes.

Additionally, the sharedMemoryUpdater is scheduled on the EDT where it will run once the event queue is empty. So, there may be a lag between when the `addDirtyRegion` is called and when `updateSharedMemory` is called. In `updateSharedMemory` there is  a call to `region.component.paint`. If any of the already queued events change `component`, the actual results of the paint call could vary.

Some suggestions as a result of testing:

Create `sharedMemoryUpdater` like this:

```
    private Runnable scheduled = null;

    sharedMemoryUpdater = Runnable {
        public void run() {
            scheduled = null;
            updateSharedMemory();
        }
    }
```

Then, in `addDirtyRegion`

```
    if (scheduled == null) {
        scheduled = sharedMemoryUpdater;
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(sharedMemoryUpdater);
    }
```

That will reduce the number of invocations of `sharedMemoryUpdater` (by 99% in my testing). As all of the calls to `addDirtyRegion` should be happening on the EDT, you shouldn't need a synchronize on `scheduled`, but adding won't hurt much.

Since there is a lag, the number of regions to process can become quite large. In my tests I saw it exceed 400 at one point.

These changes will cut the time spent manipulating the region list as it's faster to create 1 new list than create all the entries needed to copy the existing list.

```
private final Object regionLock = new Opject;
private List<PaintLog> regions = new LinkedList<PaintLog>();

// In addDirtyRegions()
synchronized(regionLock) {
    regions.add(...);
}

// In updateSharedMemory()
List<PaintLog> regionsCopy;
List<PaintLog> tmp = new LinkedList<PaintLog>()
synchronized(regionLock) {
    regionsCopy = regions;
    regions = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It does appear to make it run more efficiently, but doesn't solve the problem. In fact, when I watch it closely, it appears that the occluded component is being redrawn separately over the menu, i.e. the complete menu is painted, and then the other component is painted over it afterwards

Answer (score 0):

I'm making one assumption: that your application is running in a real graphics environment (i.e. not headless).

I think you might want to take advantage of `java.awt.Robot` which was designed to imitate a user using an AWT/Swing application. It can do things like simulating key-presses, mouse clicks, and it can **take screenshots**!  The method is `createScreenCapture(Rectangle)`, and it returns a `BufferedImage` which should be perfect for most use cases.

Here's an example, where I've included a number of vertical `JComboBox`es which overlap each other.  Opening one of these and pressing F1 will take a screenshot and show it in the preview panel below.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class ScreenshotTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JFrame f = new JFrame("Screenshot Tester");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                f.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));

                final JPanel preview = new JPanel();
                preview.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Screenshot"));
                f.add(preview, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                final JPanel testPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1));
                testPanel.add(new JComboBox(new String[] { "a", "b" }));
                testPanel.add(new JComboBox(new String[] { "c", "d" }));
                testPanel.add(new JComboBox(new String[] { "e", "f" }));
                f.add(testPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

                Action screenshotAction = new AbstractAction("Screenshot") {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                        try {
                            Rectangle region = f.getBounds();
                            BufferedImage img = new Robot().createScreenCapture(region);
                            preview.removeAll();
                            preview.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
                            f.pack();
                        } catch (AWTException e) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, e);
                        }
                    }
                };

                f.getRootPane().getActionMap().put(screenshotAction, screenshotAction);
                f.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
                        KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F1, 0), screenshotAction);
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

You should be able to see the whole window including the window decorations, and the combo-box menu should appear on top of the other combo-boxes exactly as you see it on-screen.